# Change both image and text values onclick

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have 3 variables as seen below, assume they are assigned values.
What I want to do is to insert those variables into img class "myimg2", p class "myname2" and p class "myprof2" when the user clicks the div class="info2".

It has to be in that div because I want the user to click anywhere on that div to change all 3 values.

Is this possible in Javascript?

Javscript:

```
var storeOnClick, 
    name,
    prof;
```

HTML

```
<table class="table2" rules="rows">
<tr>
<td>
<div class="info2" onclick="changeStats(this)" >
<div  style="float:left">
<img class="myimg2"style="max-height:80px;" src="Pictures/QuestionMark.png">
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<p class="myname2">Name: Jane Doe</p>
<p class="myprof2">Profession: Something</p>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="info2" onclick="changeStats(this)" >
<div  style="float:left">
<img class="myimg2"style="max-height:80px;" src="Pictures/QuestionMark.png">
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<p class="myname2">Name: Jane Doe</p>
<p class="myprof2">Profession: Something</p>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't use Jquery in this example :( but if thats the only possible way, it would be interesting to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got the code.  The way I'm doing it is attaching an event handler to the `body` of the page.  Then in that function, I detect if you clicked on a `.info` element (or one of it's children). If you did, then I change out the values of that particular `.info` div

Super important parts:

```
// add an event listener to the entire body. I could have iterated through each div with the '.info2' class instead
if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', updateCard, false);
} else {
    document.body.attachEvent('onclick',updateCard); // stupid IE
}


// this is the callback function for the click event handler
function updateCard(e) {
   e = e || window.event;
   var target = e.target || e.srcElement; // more IE stuff

   // does target have an ancestor of .info2 ?
    var el = findAncestor(target, 'info2');
    if (el) {

      // which elements do we want to update? Only the currently clicked on .info2
      var iImg = el.querySelector('.myimg2');
      var iName = el.querySelector('.myname2');
      var iProf = el.querySelector('.myprof2');


      // assign the values a random element from the arrays
      storeOnClick = imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArray.length)];
      name = nameArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*nameArray.length)];
      prof = profArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*profArray.length)];


      iImg.src = storeOnClick;
      iName.innerHTML = lblName + name;
      iProf.innerHTML = lblProf + prof;  
   }     
}

// this is similar to jQuery's $.parents('.class')
function findAncestor (el, cls) {
    while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.classList.contains(cls));
    return el;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/onejdc/BJdmu/1/)

For fun, here's what it might look like in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $('.info2').on("click",function() {
       var t = $(this);
       t.find('.myimg2').attr('src',storeOnClick);
       t.find('.myname2').html(name);
       t.find('.prof2').html(prof);
   });
});
```

Comment: For some reason it's only changing the first div="info2", I have multiple of them, 12 1 after another in the table. Might this have something to do with the [0]??

Comment: Yes, when I change the [0] to [1] it changes the next div only - is there any way to change the [x] to the number of the div onclick?

Comment: Yes, you have to loop through each element. I simply specified individual ones. I'll update the demo and code.  Actually, do you want to click on the first div and it update all of the images with the same result, or do you want to click on say, the third div, and have it update just the one you clicked on?

Comment: Just the one I clicked on :)

Comment: Ok, updated the jsFiddle. it should work for any number of table elements.

Comment: Thanks, the Jsfiddle seems to have died by the way :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Insert the new `onClick` in `info2`:

```
<div class="info2" onclick="change_text()">
```

Also change `class` to `ID` for your fields. For example: `class="myname2"` to `id="myname2"`

Javascript:

```
function change_text() {
    var text1 = document.getElementById('myname2');
    var text2 = document.getElementById('myprof2');
    var img1 = document.getElementById("myimg2");

    if (text1.innerHTML === "Name: Jane Doe") {
        text1.innerHTML = "test";
    }
    if (text2.innerHTML === "Profession: Something") {
        text2.innerHTML = "test";
    }
    if (img1.src == "link here") {
            img1.src = "link here";
    }
}
```

Kinda messy method but it will be easier for you to understand from this method :)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h6MSg/1)**

Comment: There are multiple entities in the table so I would have to be able to click on them separately to change them individually

Comment: Updated it for you :)

Comment: I can't get it to change the contents of the next div in the table, when I put the onclick into the next div - it just changes the first div's content :(

Comment: Because my function is only for the first div :) `<div class="info2" onclick="change_text()">` you will have to use a function on each `div`. It will be pretty messy